# Create and access zip file from resource folder during runtime in java spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, zip

My requirement is, I have to create one zip file and store in resource folder and once it's created, i have to pass this zip file to another api(which one will accept only .zip file as a input)through rest template.

Now my problem is after creating zip file im not able to access it. I think this is because the file is not available in target folder.

How to solve this problem?

Note: all these activities should happen in a single call.

Technology: java 11, spring boot, maven Latest

Comment: When is this ZIP file created? If during development, then just include it with your other resources and access it like any other class-path resource. If it's at run-time, then this ZIP file is not a resource, and should not be stored as such. Resources should be, and typically are, read-only anyway. Perhaps you should create the ZIP file in a temporary directory instead.

Comment: If i create it in temp folder then how can i fetch and pass to resttemplate as multipart file

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Spring, but I assume you would pass a `java.io.File` or `java.nio.file.Path` to whatever API of Spring you're using (assuming Spring doesn't have its own API for files and temporary directories/files).

Comment: Hi @Slaw , thanks for your suggestion. I fixed that issue and able to access the file using FileSystemResource() .

Answer (score 0):

the resource folder is normaly part of a jar.  i would create a temp folder (java.nio.file.Files.createTempDirectory()) and store the zip there.

Comment: thanks for your help. I fixed it with temp direcory.

Comment: don't forget to delete the folder at the end...